# Accessing NuGet functionality from behind a corporate firewall

Tags: visual-studio-2010

When I right mouse click on the References folder in the Solution Explorer window and selecct "Add Package Reference Library", I get teh error

The package source named "NuGet official package source https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=206669 is eiether invalid or not available and thus is unreachable"

When I use IE directly to access this URL, I am redirected to http://packages.nuget.org/v1/FeedService.svc/ and see an XML response.

I suspect that my company's security is preventing me from accessing this site. I'd like to request that they make an exception. What specifically should I request that would enable me to access it?

And similarly, I would like to access the Extnsion Manager functionality from within VS but I get a more vague "An error occured error" ..

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a [known issue](http://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/227886) with NuGet. I've been getting the same error and I updated to the latest version of NuGet but still get the error when using the proxy, but everything works when the proxy is disabled. I'm not sure when they will have this resolved.